# Como fazer um determinado link de um iframe carregue em toda a pagina

Tags: html, iframe

Exemplo:

```
<iframe scr="https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=WKaFVtKXJ8yG8Qec97KwCg#q=stack+overflow"></iframe>
```

> ***Uma pesquisa simples no google para o site Stack Overflow***

Eu queria que, quando fosse clicado no link (pt.stackoverflow.com), ele carregasse toda a pagina para o respectivo link.

---

Em resumo, que um determinado link do iframe fosse carregado como uma pagina normal(ou seja usando refresh).

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso porque não tem como você alterar o comportamento de páginas externas dentro do iframe.

Comment: @DavidFernandes no cazo a pagina que vai ser vai ser a minha na parte de login so que depois de ele fazer o login ele acessa normal com o redfresh